# How to redirect specific name only domain with https to another domain

Tags: nginx

i have NGINX  server which is targeting by two domain https://a.com and https://b.com . i want that if url come from **only** https://a.com then should redirect to https://b.com . in short my server should serve as https://b.com to all coming **https** links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server {    # traffic from http://a.com will redirect to https://b.com
    listen      80;
    server_name *.a.com;

    return 301 https://b.com$request_uri;
}

server {    # traffic from https://a.com will redirect to https://b.com
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name *.a.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/your/certs/a.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/certs/a.com.key;

    ...

    return 301 https://b.com$request_uri;
}

server {    # will serve your app
    listen  443 ssl default_server;

    server_name *.b.com;

    ssl_certificate     /path/to/your/certs/b.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/your/certs/b.com.key;

    ...

    location / {
        root        /path/to/your/app;
        index       index.html;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its wokring